# String not working with cin!

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue with my simple Hello World code.

I'm not able to `cin` my name. It says no defined operator ">>" Can someone help please. Below is my code.

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       int x;
       string name;
       cout<< "enter name:";
       cin>> name;
       cout<< "Hello "<< name <<endl;



       system("Pause");
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to 
    `#include <string>`.

Comment: And whatever it is you need to include for `system`. Or just ditch that kludge.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: I do understand that this is the correct answer, but why the compiler doesn't complain without any header included for string?

Comment: @Als: Some compilers include parts of other Standard headers in headers. It's legal to include *all* of another header, but I don't know about only part.

Comment: @DeadMG: If compiler didn't compile about `string` type without it's include then it could interpret the type through some include, then why the error then?

Comment: @Als: I don't know. FWIW, g++-4.6 doesn't complain at all with the OP's original code.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: I know i checked it and hence the Q, http://www.ideone.com/6P61t

Comment: @Als: It is quite common to include some of the definitions in other headers. The standard states the minimum definitions that a translation unit will have if it includes a particular header, but more definitions can be added by the implementation. If you are using `std::string`, you should include `<string>`, and the fact that in most cases it seems to work makes things harder to notice when they fail. It is, for example, quite common for `<iostream>` to include the definition of `std::string`, but not `std::getline( std::istream&, std::string& )`

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: Thanks, David! As always to the point! :)

Comment: Thankyou for your answer! I have seen other codes that don't include the STRING...but it works.